# Removing all notification observer from all view controllers in swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4, nsnotificationcenter

There is any way to remove `notification observer` from all view controllers at one time (or from current view controller).

Comment: No, There's no any way to do this.

Comment: Thanx kuldeep but there are any jugard for this.

Comment: Why not post a remove observer notification then let the listeners delete themselves. Something like NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "RemoveUrSelves", object: nil). Just make sure that you register the viewcontrollers first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: sorry chirag but this is for only one VC

Comment: you can create a one method to remove all view controller notification observer.

Comment: I want that method for me in answer